# Want to set a proxy flag (just like apache) in NGINX

Tags: nginx

In Apache

```
rewriterule  acution(.*)$ xyz.com$1 [P]
```

due to that `[P]` flag  user will get only the original IP or domain.

---

In Nginx

```
rewrite acution(.*)$ http://xyz.com$1;
```

now I want to do same thing set a proxy flag `[P]` so that  user will get only the original domain name instead of http://xyz.com.

Please guide how to achieve the same.